# Django Docker Image Recreation

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

As I have created DOCKERFILE file and docker-compose file.

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libssl-dev

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 
COPY . /code
 
EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python /code/manage.py runserver"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  django_app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Once I am making any changes in django requirements file then all the time I have to delete all the images from my system then I have to recreate the whole images by downloading and installing ubuntu images rather be only installing the requirements.

Currently I am using this command to run the docker
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`.

Please help me to understand where I am doing wrong in the process.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually delete anything to update your image.  You may need to specify `docker-compose up --build` to force the image(s) to get rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) way to start a docker-compose file is with:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

which by default looks for that file **docker-compose.yaml**